# calling a simple WCF Service from jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have a very simple WCF Service called pilltrkr.svc.  I'm trying to call this service from jQuery via the following code:

```
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: './pilltrakr.svc/DoWork/',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: jsondata,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
            //                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
```

I am doing this locally (so using localhost).  DoWork just returns a string.  When I call this function I get a **http://localhost:57400/pilltrakr/pilltrakr.svc/DoWork/ 404 Not Found**

How do I call my WCF Service?  I've tried several different variations (after researching).  I was able to call this service using the code behind method (client).  I'm sure this is a real easy thing to do.  Please advise.

**More code -**

It seems like every post on Stack includes the interface and the actual class for the service, so I am also putting them here, just in case there is something I'm missing:

**Interface:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace serviceContract
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "Ipilltrakr" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface Ipilltrakr
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        string DoWork();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        int addUser(string userName, string userPhone, string userEmail, string userPwd, string acctType);
    }
}
```

**class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using pillboxObjects;

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace serviceContract
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "pilltrakr" in code, svc and config file together.
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class pilltrakr : Ipilltrakr
    {


        string Ipilltrakr.DoWork()
        {
            return "got here";
        }


        int Ipilltrakr.addUser(string userName, string userPhone, string userEmail, string userPwd, string acctType)
        {
            userAccount ua = new userAccount();
            int uId;

            ua.userName = userName;
            ua.userPhone = userPhone;
            ua.userEmail = userEmail;
            ua.userPwd = userPwd;
            ua.userCreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            ua.userAccountType = acctType;

            uId = ua.add();

            return uId;
        }
    }
}
```

**web config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxxConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Ipilltrakr" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:57400/pilltrakr/pilltrakr.svc/pilltrakr"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Ipilltrakr"
        contract="svcPilltrakr.Ipilltrakr" name="BasicHttpBinding_Ipilltrakr" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="serviceContract.pilltrakr" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint contract="serviceContract.Ipilltrakr" binding="basicHttpBinding" address="pilltrakr" bindingNamespace="serviceContract"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think WCF services are, by default, SOAP services, and it's going to be tricky to call them directly from Javascript. You could look into using something like webHttpBinding, or WCF Web API, or proxying the WCF call through an .asmx.

Comment: @Sii - There are a ton of examples of calling WCF Services via jQuery.  I think I'm just missing something simple that will get me over my hurdle.

Comment: Maybe it's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webscriptservicehostfactory.aspx ?

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service this post might help you...

Comment: @patel.milanb - I tried implementing it the way he is doing it and I get nothing...  plus now my original asp.net calls don't work...  It also seems that his example is building off of something that isn't being shown (endpoints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to finally call my simple WCF service from jQuery.  I found some source code after reading this link:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/15/Making-jQuery-calls-to-WCFASMX-with-a-ServiceProxy-Client.  This link doesn't provide the source but it was another page that referenced this link.

Anyway, I downloaded the code and started to compare my code versus this working project that was calling a WCF Service via jQuery.  What I found was that my web.config file was way too complicated so I shorted that up considerably.  Then I also realized that my methods were not public.  So I made them public and then after a few more tweaks (i.e. taking out the namespaces) the page started to return the simple string I was trying to return.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="pilltrakr" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="pilltrakrAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Ipilltrakr"/>        
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="pilltrakrAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably a bit late, but I wrote a couple of blog posts a few years ago about calling WCF from jQuery.  This also covers fault handling - which many articles ignore.

[Part one](http://iainjmitchell.com/blog/?p=97) and [Part two](http://iainjmitchell.com/blog/?p=142).

HTH

Iain

Comment: I read part 1 and that was a great write up.  I'm looking at part 2 now.

Answer (score -1):

what i found in google, might help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("#sayHelloButton").click(function(event){
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "dummyWebsevice.svc/HelloToYou",
                 data: "{'name': '" + $('#name').val() + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(msg) {
                     AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                 },
                 error: AjaxFailed
             });
         });
     });
          function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
              alert(result.d);
          }
          function AjaxFailed(result) {
              alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
          }  

[WebMethod()]
public static string sayHello()
{
    return "hello ";
}
```

Comment: is this a WCF Service?  Or a classic web service?

Comment: -1 for not addressing the nature of the question and providing an irrelevant answer (i.e. the question related to WCF web services, not classic ASP.NET web methods).