# calling wcf service from html always goes to error function. Works fine with aspx page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, wcf

I have created a simple webservice which is hosted in same domain.

Now, I have created two pages

1) Aspx page where I'll be calling that webservice and it works just fine. Code is pasted below:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

First Name:
    
     Last Name:

```
    $(function () {

        $("#btnSayHello").click(function () {

            var txtFirstName = $("#MainContent_txtFirstName").val();
            var txtSecondName = $("#MainContent_txtLastName").val();
            $("#MainContent_lblResult").html("Hello " + txtFirstName + " " + txtSecondName);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "json",
                datatTypes: "json",
                url: "http://10.24.104.196/TestServiceCore.svc/GetName/",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        })
    });

</script>
```

This thing works just fine..

2) I've tried using same javascript code for an simple HTML page (code as shown below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Employee Hub
    


    
        Employee Hub - A Basic Test Application

```
    </section>
</form>
<input id="btnSayHello" type="button" value="Get Value From WCF" /><br />
<label for="male" id="lblResult">Test</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#btnSayHello").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "json",
                datatTypes: "json",
                url: "http://10.24.104.196/TestServiceCore.svc/GetName/",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    //alert('error; ' + eval(result));
                    window.alert("eRROR");
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

for this case it always goes to error function.

Not sure what's going wrong here for error it only produces "object object"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: I am still having this problem... and the problem area for this issue is only in AJAX call. calling the URL otherwise works fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Added [source code link](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6&id=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6!2050) to repo this issue.

Comment: a typo in 'datatTypes' ? Are you opening your html file through the webserver or through the file system ?

Comment: Actually I've created a webapplication project in VS2012 and launching from there.
Even if I try to launch that page from file system it still has the same behaviour. btw I fixed that typo in 'datatTypes' but still the same issue

Comment: Sure the masterpage does not include some ajaxSetup or prefilter which does not get applied through your html page ? btw It won't work through the filesystem. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: okay.. so in that case what I need to do to fix that.. basically I am quite new for this html webthingi stuff.. :D thanks for your help in advance !!

Comment: I'm afraid you should start from the html produced by the aspx page, save it as html, and remove code until it does not work anymore. This way, you may find what is needed.

Comment: I see.. but that doesn't seems to be working fine.. :-( 

I've just created an empty website project and then added a new html page but still not much luck.. getting the same error

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621528/calling-a-simple-wcf-service-from-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo error in the  source code you provided ,rename `datatTypes` to `datatType`

i have checked the code from the link you provided and it is working fine.